# Nginx "load_module" directive is not allowed here

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a perfectly fine nginx setup. However, now I would like to load modules, so I have

```
load_module modules/ndk_http_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_set_misc_module.so;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;
    more_clear_headers 'Server';
    more_clear_headers 'X-Powered-By';


    location / {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    ...
}
```

Now, when I try to start I get the following error

```
"load_module" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1
```

I'm using Docker, so `default.conf` is my `nginx.conf`

```
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

I've tried to add `http { ... }` around everything, but then I get a similar error for `http`. The only thing that might be wrong (I think) is that `COPY` action. Should `nginx.conf be copied to` /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`? Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't the top level `nginx.conf` file. It's an include file. The file containing the `http { ... }` block will be located at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Comment: Please keep in mind that StackOverflow focuses on programming problems. This looks like a question that is more on-topic on serverfault.com